# Generation of formatted files with Ruby in the way how it can be done with PHP

Tags: php, ruby, buffering, output-buffering

I use PHP to generate files of some special format, and I have decided to try the same thing with Ruby. To make a file with PHP, I use the following code:

```
<? include 'functions_and_settings.php'; ob_start() ?>

some parts of another format

<? // php functions generating file content, 
   // including other formatted files ?>

some parts

<? file_put_contents('output.fmt', ob_get_clean()) ?>
```

Is it possible to do with Ruby? How would you do this?

---

**Update**

The following code is equivalent to the PHP one:

```
require 'erb'
require 'my_functions_and_settings'
template = ERB.new <<-EOF

some text lines of another format

<% #functions generating content,
   # inclusion of formatted files %>

some text lines of another format

EOF
File.open("output.fmt", "w") do |f|
  f.puts template.result(binding)
end
# or may be:  File.new("file.txt") << template.result(binding)
```

Is there a way to do `ruby file.erb >> output.fmt`?

---

**Update2**

Standard Ruby distribution has `erb` processor

```
/usr/bin/erb  my_formatted_file.erb
```

Comment: Can you make your example more concrete? Where is your data coming from? What would an example output file look like? Ruby can be pretty elegant for this type of job, but without a lot more detail it's pretty hard to work out how to help.

Comment: Assume that I am generating a text file. It is used by another program knowing which will not really help. The problem which I am facing with is output buffering in the way how PHP allows to do. I will try ERB for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this but the most common is probably [erb](http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html). This allows you to   provide a template and then embed ruby command within <% %> symbols. In much the same way as you do with PHP. This is how most Ruby-On-Rails applications render their views.

There is a short review of 19 different ruby templating engines (Some of which are XML/HTML specific) available [here](http://www.hokstad.com/mini-reviews-of-19-ruby-template-engines.html)

Comment: ERB looks like a good solution. Is there a way to parse ERB-file without `require 'erb'; out = ERB.new <<...`? Preferably via console (something like `ruby -erb file.erb`)? Also my format is using `%` for comments and I cannot change this. Is there a way to turn off the %-rule?

Comment: Concerning %, it seems that it is off by default and one can turn it on by ERB.new(template,0,**'*'**)

Comment: ruby has a -r flag to require a library before executing the script